# How can I use enum written in idl in same project (MFC Control)

Tags: mfc, idl

I have a MFC control that has an idl file "Test.idl" where I define some enum.

However, if I want to use this enum in the MFC control, I have to include the auto generated header "Testidl.h" that is created by midl.

Ok, but I have a periodic problem. If the autogenerated file "Testidl.h" is not existing, I cannot include that file, thus, cannot compile my control and, thus, cannot create the autogenerated file.

The problem is (I guess), hat the MIDL step is done AFTER C++ build.

Am I correct and can I solve this behaviour somehow?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the IDL file is included in the project's Source Files list the MIDL step should be done first and generate the associated .h file.